# Android Emulator: Failed to pull selection

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Android 2.2 emulator. When I'm trying to pull a file from DDMS-file explorer, it says:

```
[2012-02-08 02:52:52] Failed to pull selection
[2012-02-08 02:52:52] (null)
```

Why and what to do with it?

Answer (score 150):

You might have forgotten to re-select the device in the left pane. For some reason, it needs to be refreshed and the previous selection is invalid.

Comment: Thanks! so simple but powerfull :)

Comment: Not sure why this answer hasn't been accepted. It worked for me and judging by the votes it worked for a lot of others too

Comment: I see only IP address of my device connected to my PC through Wifi in the left pane. Even after selecting it in the left pane, pulling did not work. Then I copied the database file to some other folder on the device and pulled it. It worked! I am using Juno version of eclipse.

Comment: Happy that it's useful

Comment: Thanks! This also worked for DDMS launched via Android Studio 1.1.0

Answer (score 32):

Restart Eclipse (Close and open it again). That would be sufficient.

Comment: @Ravi This works, but restarting Eclipse for every occurrence is **REALLY** getting annoying. Why is this happening?

Comment: @AndroidAddict You can use command line to do a Pull. Follow this:  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/186210-pushpull-from-emulator-in-eclipse/page__p__1091995&#entry1091995 (Make sure that android sdk tools folder is in your environment variable). This will make it less annoying :)

Comment: @Ravi thanks for the link - appreciate it!  Just an FYI, this is happening with a device, not an emulator.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using DDMS from Eclipse IDE this can happen if the device is not selected in the Devices window in the left pane of the DDMS view.

It seems the IDE can show you a menu of files in the right hand 'file explorer' window even if you have not selected a device. This can happen, for example, if you previously were using DDMS and then return to the view (possibly having restarted or disconnect the device - have not tested it in depth).

To solve this simply select the device in the left 'Devices' pane within DDMS - no need to restart Eclipse (Eclipse Juno).

Comment: Clearly an Eclipse/DDMS bug.

Answer (score 2):

Try to reboot your computer. Sometimes the DDMS File Explorer doesn't respond.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168955/problem-pulling-file-from-emulator-using-gui-or-adb-command) more info.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't have the permission to access the db file. E.g. you're working on a real device or androidx86 (I had this problem with androidx86 running on Virtaul Box)

One solution worked for me (on windows):

1. open cmd
2. browse to your adb folder with cd command (".../sdk/platform-tools/")
3. type in:

   1. adb shell
   2. su
   3. chmod 777 data/.../database.db (folder containing the database file on your android device)

now it should work (maybe you have to restart ecplise)

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same error, then i certainly find that this error was due to the incorrect name of database,in my case

```
private static String DATABASE_NAME = "vpmsn.db ";
```

as you can see there is a **space** after vpmsn.db what actually was happening is that the database was being created successfully but as there is a space after the database name so when you try to pull the database the above error occured,hope this will help any one who is suffering from same error

Answer (score 0):

just open your command prompt and navigate it to ur abd file location(D:\Apps\android\4.0.3\platform-tools) just type in the command prompt as **adb install filename.apk** it  works fine without getting any errors... you should have to do this with ur emulator running otherwise it fails...

Answer (score 0):

First, grant permission to acces your data folder ,  with cmd to your C:\Users\pcjava\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

```
In cmd Type 'adb shell'
su
Press 'Allow' on device
chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.yourapplication.package /data/data/com.yourapplication.package/*
```

Second, grant permission to your database.db that you are trying to pull

```
adb shell
su
root@android:/ # chmod 777 /data/data/com.ht.mt.siiv/databases/nameOfMyDatabase
```