# failed to pull selection null

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, ddms

when i try to save my database on desktop to edit it with SQLite browser i have do like this

in File Explorer Tab you will follow the path :

data > data > my-package-name > databases > my-database-file.

i select the file, click on the disket icon and oups i have this errors in console,

```
failed to pull selection 
null
```

my methode :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.creeruncompte);
            db=openOrCreateDatabase("DBProjet",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Client ( _id integer primary key, NomClient VARCHAR,PrenomClient VARCHAR,Email VARCHAR,MotPasse VARCHAR);");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PointVisite ( _idp integer primary key , NomPoint VARCHAR,Adresse VARCHAR,Info VARCHAR,Commentaire VARCHAR);");

        }
```

i google it and find some [how fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182190/failed-to-pull-selection)  and other but nothing work

can you help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just a poor experience of me, sorry, i just restart my pc and it's gone okay

Comment: restarting would be a solution, but why would you do that if a better way is there! see my answer...'

Answer (score 13):

Just re-selecting the device from the left panel would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is just restart your adb. open command prompt and do this.

`adb kill-server
adb start-server`