# Android Eclipse DDMS - Can't pull file from rooted device

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, ddms

I am testing my app on a rooted Nexus S phone. I finally have access to the /data/data folder thanks to some awesome help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867379/android-eclipse-ddms-cant-access-data-data-on-phone-to-pull-files/8896049#8896049).

Problem is when I try to use DDMS to "pull a file from the device" I get this error:

```
[2012-03-20 18:15:26] Failed to pull selection
[2012-03-20 18:15:26] (null)
```

Anyone know how to pull a copy of the database so I can look at it in a SQLite editor?

Comment: I have same issue and i have fixed that see my answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14752672/1939564

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out that to pull the actual database file (my_database.db) you have to use chmod on that specific file in the adb shell. So you need to explicitly define the path to the database you want to access.

For example, if the database file were my_database.db and the application package was com.example.database, you would need to call the following:

1) In cmd type: adb shell
2) Type: su
3) Press "allow" on the **rooted** phone
4) In cmd type: chmod 777 /data/data/com.example.database/databases/my_database.db
5) Go to DDMS in Eclipse
6) Navigate to the my_database.db file and select it
7) Choose "pull a file from the device" and choose where to save it

Comment: I had to chmod 777 every folder on the way to the database file. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, that is typically how you have to do it. chmod 777 allows you access to folders/files. If you haven't used chmod 777 on a folder previously, none of it's contents will be accessible to continue drilling down.

Comment: how to do this on a non-rooted phone?

Answer (score 2):

Restart your eclipse once. I hope that will fix this issue

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168955/problem-pulling-file-from-emulator-using-gui-or-adb-command

Comment: Restarting Eclipse didn't work. Rebooting the computer didn't either. I am developing on a MacBook with OSX 7. This may be a Mac specific issue...